# Hotend temperature goes to infinity after few layers

Tags: marlin, hotend, ramps-1.4, reprap

I have a "classic" home built 3D printer, Arduino Mega, RAMPS 1.4 with Marlin 2.0.

It worked, was put in storage, and now I am trying to get it running again.

During all of the testing phases, the PID autotune, etc., the temperature of the hotend is stable.

When printing, for a few layers (4-5), the temperature is OK, despite the part fan coming on and off. However, after 3-4 mm of printing the temperature just rises and rises and rises, and after 275 °C thermal protection kicks in...

MOSFETs have additional cooling and a fan over them.

I'm out of ideas... Help!!!

My config files and G-code are [here](https://github.com/hergiz/singles)

Using PrusaSlicer.

Why do I see a temperature rise on the display? Last time I unplugged the printer and left it on USB power then gave it power again. During USB power temperature was steadily going down, as soon I plugged the main cable it resumed printing and the temperature rising again.

I did another test. 20mm above bed started printing, and got same result. I captured on video entire process [Hot end to orbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_1puCo07to). Around 2 min 30 sec the show begins.

Comment: Can you post a link to the gcode you were printing as well?

Comment: G code added to git.

Comment: How are you printing PLA at 175 C?  Or did I not look far enough in the gcode?

Comment: At 180 C. Tried first at 200, all ok. This is a new spool. Before that one I printed with PETG at 230 C. No problems. Afcore, every print ends up the same, after 2.5 mm into print head goes inferno :)

Comment: Can you try putting a shim over the Z-stop limit switch so the print starts higher, then "dry print" (no filament) to see if this still happens at the same physical height (relative to the machine frame) or after the same number of layers?

Comment: Or alternately, retract or unload filament, preheat the nozzle, and jog the Z axis up 0.1 mm at a time, then wait a minute after each jog to see if the temperature starts to take off.

Comment: Probably a thermistor cable fault (short-circuit). Does part of the cable flex about a particular point, or is it strapped tightly to other cables or structures? That can lead to cable failure, and thermistor cables do not seem to be particularly robust.

Comment: @Mick That's what my suggested tests are aimed at.  Same height relative to machine frame suggests a cable fault.

Comment: Ok. I see your point. Cabels are neatly packed, with that black mesh sleave. I will definitly try the test in hour or two. But... If it was cable problem, or termistor problem of any king, why do I see temperature rise at display? Last time I unplugged printer and left it on USB power, then gave it power again. During USB power temperature was going down, as soon I plugged main cable it resumed printing and temperature rising again.

Comment: Thermistors read a resistance related to temperature.  If the cable shorts, that resistance goes to zero (= cold, IIRC), and if the cable disconnects, it goes to infinity (= hot).  This not just jumping suggests it isn't that simple, but my tests will still narrow down whether it's related to print time/layer steps or physical height relative to the frame.

Comment: I did a test, and posted video. I edited original question.

Comment: I don't know what a "classic home-built 3D printer is", but you can troubleshoot a problem like this by tracing it backwards. Why is the hot-end heating up? Because the heater is still on. Why is the heater still on? Two possibilities: either the software is telling it to be on, or there's a hardware fault causing it to be on even though the software is telling it to be off. Let's say it's the software. Then why is the software doing that? Some possibilities: faulty sensor says it's cold, target temperature set too high, software bug. etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is in fact of a hardware nature. By replacing RAMPS 1.4, the problem went away.

Arduino, firmware, G-code... everything is the same, only RAMPS was replaced.

I'm going to find a suitable MOSFET replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a short in your sensor or sensor circuitry.  However, if this is the case the sensed temperature is higher than the actual hotend temperature.  Does your hot end go cold when the sensed temperature takes off?  A short could also show the hotend temperature going up at an unrealistically fast rate.  This doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: No. When temperature goes up, so is nozzle shoveling, and after error is detected, I have to wait for the head to cool of to be able to lit Z axes it leaves a big hole around nozzle...